# Orientation issue with child activity for tabactivity android

Tags: android, android-activity, screen-orientation, android-tabs

I am developing an application where I have a tab activity and 4 child activities(Tabs). Now in my second tab I need to send one bluetooth request on every time i start this activity so I added this code in onResume() method. But when I rotate tab when secondtab is active it resend request on every rotation. I added config:changes in manifest for all tabs but not on main tabactivity as I have two different layouts for tabactivity.
Main issue is even though I added configchanges still second tab reloading on every rotation.
Is there any solution to avoid screen rotation in child tab.

Edit:: Main thing is when I rotate device screen rotate but if I write config.changes in manifiest for that activity it should call onCreate() again. But as I am using tabacitivity this is not happing in child activity....

Comment: in your `<activity>` set attribute `android:screenOrientation=portrait`

Comment: @MuhammadBabar -- I want give rotation support but no need to call onCreate() everytime screen rotates...

Comment: than you need this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html